# Maven: How to manage dependency from one child module to another child module

Tags: maven, parent-child, maven-resources-plugin, maven-install

I have maven parent-child project where parent has multiple child modules. One of the child module is generating a jar and other one is depending on that jar.

Project structure is like: One parent module which has three child modules. Each one has its own pom.xml. Child1 generates jar file and others are generating war file. Where only Child3 is dependent on Child1 jar.

Is there a best way to manage such type of dependency using pom.xml.

[image: Project Structure]

Updated: When I am adding dependency in Child3 I am able to build Child3 module but when I am trying to deploy it on tomcat it throws an error as:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/ifxforum/xsd/_1/CIMBAcctInfoInqSvc
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975)
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:613)
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:524)
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:510)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.determineCandidateConstructors(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:247)
... 57 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.ifxforum.xsd._1.CIMBAcctInfoInqSvc
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1275)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1104)
... 64 more
```

And my dependency in Child3's pom.xml as:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>myGroupId</groupId>
        <artifactId>myArtifactId</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/lib/myJar.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
```

I can see **org/ifxforum/xsd/_1/CIMBAcctInfoInqSvc** is in jar.

Comment: Can make a ascii picture of that structure to get a better understanding of your structure?

Comment: @khmarbaise Please see image for project structure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just declare a maven dependency in Child3 on the coordinates of Child1. For the version, you can use `${project.version}`.

Comment: Thanks for comments. I followed your comment but facing some issue Please check updated question above.

Comment: Avoid the system path. Maven does not need a path to reference another module in the same multi-module project.

Comment: Thanks JF Meier you saved my weekend. As per your comments its working fine.